# Query giving repeated salary columns for date series between two dates

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Hi I want the dates and the corresponding values unique in postgres
I have  a table in which startdate, enddate and salary is given. I want to calculate the seies of dates and the salary for the period. the table is like

```
Salary Startdate    Enddate
1000   "2015-09-28" "2015-09-30"
```

i want query result is like

```
dates      salary
2015-09-28 1000
2015-09-29 
2015-09-30
```

The query i am using is

```
select salary, generate_series("startdate", "enddate", '1 day'::interval)::date as date from tablename
where id=4
```

But it's giving the result as

```
dates      salary
2015-09-28  1000
2015-09-29  1000 
2015-09-30  1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sub-select to create the series of dates from `tablename` and then a `LEFT JOIN` to add the salary data:

```
SELECT d.dates, t.salary
FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(startdate, enddate, interval '1 day') dates
  FROM tablename) d
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON t.startdate = d.dates;
```

Assuming you have more salary data in your table, you would have to change the join clause to include more qualifiers, like an `employee_id` or so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach:

```
with cte as (
  select
    generate_series(startdate, enddate, '1 day'::interval)::date as date,
    salary, startdate
  from tablename
  where id=4
)
select
  date,
  case when date = startdate then salary end as salary
from cte
```

However, I will tell you this may not be bulletproof.  For example, if your data looks like this:

```
Salary Startdate    Enddate
1000   2015-09-28   2015-09-30
1000   2015-10-01   2015-10-05
```

You will still have a second 1000 entry for 10/1/15.

A more bulletproof but far less efficient way to do it would be to use the `lag` analytic function, which would evaluate everything above but also take into consideration the previous salary:

```
with cte as (
  select
    generate_series(startdate, enddate, '1 day'::interval)::date as date,
    salary, startdate,
    lag(salary) over (partition by id order by startdate) as prior_sal
  from tablename
  where id=4
)
select
  date,
  case
    when (prior_sal is null or prior_sal != salary) and
      date = startdate then salary
  end as salary
from cte
```

Depending on how likely this situation would be to occur may help determine which is the better approach.